# SQL syntax error at simple statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to execute

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_new_password';
```

but getting

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'my_new_password'' at line 1

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Which version are you using? That SQL works from 5.7.6 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you want to change the password is only valid since MySQL 5.7.6. You can use the [`SET PASSWORD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html) statement for older versions instead:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('my_new_password');
```

The [`ALTER USER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-user.html) statement is available since MySQL 5.7.6. Make sure you are using this version or a newer one to use your statement (thx [@Dez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305953/dez)).

Comment: The way he wants to change the password is valid since version 5.7.6.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-user.html